# Can't render model's property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Asking for help with Angular.
Somewhy, cannot refresh property (timerValue) when its value is changed. It does render it once.

Here's html div:

```
<div>{{ game.timerValue }}</div>
```

The js:

```
// Game status
$scope.game = {
    "started"    : false,
    "timerValue" : 60,
    "score"      : 0,
    "question"   : "? ? ?",
    "message"    : "If all options are set up, then you may start!",
    "wrong"      : ""
  };
 // Handle Start Button click
  $scope.startGame = function () {    

    if($scope.game.timer) clearTimeout($scope.game.timer);

    $scope.game.score = 0;
    $scope.game.wrong = "";    
    $scope.game.message = "The game started!";

    $scope.game.timer = setInterval(function() {      
      $scope.game.timerValue -= 1;
      if( $scope.game.timerValue <= 0)
      {
        $scope.game.message = "Defeat! Time is out! Your score is " + $scope.game.score;
        clearTimeout($scope.game.timer);
      }
    },1000);
  };
```

Running out of ideas, thanks for any help.

**Update:** The property is changed, the timer is working. It is not refreshing.

Comment: Where you are calling this function on Onchange in template ?

Comment: Sorry being unclear. Not onchage event. I mean when the value of the property "$scope.game.timer" changes. It changes with timer. Timer is working properly, and actually the value changes. It doesn't refresh.

Comment: you may need to do a `$scope.apply()` at the end of each interval. though that doesn't seem like the best solution, since this may create confilicts if you try to do a `$scope.apply()` any where else

Comment: yeah ) but $scope.$apply(). Thanks a lot. Can you post answer, i will accept?

Comment: I posted my answer below. Pretty much in line with what everyone else is saying.

Comment: Just to be an annoying pedant (and to prevent misconceptions), there are no possible conflicts that can arise from using `$scope.apply()` here that would not also apply to $interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of each interval to get what you want to achieve. just be wary of confilicts if you try to do a `$scope.$apply()` any where inside this function (if you were to extend it) or outside, if you were to extend the function that calls this.

You could also do what @Discosultan suggested and use `$interval`, which should automatically apply changes to your view from the scope at the end of each interval and will not create conflicts if you use a `$scope.$apply()` elsewhere in your code. By using `$interval` it will become part of your digest cycle, and you want to make sure not to put to much computational heavy code inside your digest loop otherwise it could slow down your entire app, as explained below in the comments by @AlvinThompson

Comment: "this may create confilicts if you try to do a $scope.apply() any where else" -- can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think conflicts only occur when you try to call `$scope.apply` when you're already in a digest cycle, which is not the case here.

Comment: no it is not the case here. and yes it only causes conflict if it's during a digest cycle. But often people do not post the code for their entire page, only what is relevant to the question. So if somewhere else in the code there was a `$scope.apply(),` attached to some sort of on-click event for example, it could cause a conflict, especially given that this `$scope.apply()` is being called every interval, and the two digest cycles could run concurrently.

Comment: ...but since he's explicitly using `setInterval` and supplying the function to it, that particular thread of execution is guaranteed to be outside of the digest cycle, regardless of any other code. If you can come up with a counterexample please supply it.

Comment: So say you use setTimeout, before the game starts to set `game.question` and the interval is 5 seconds for setInterval and the `setTimeout` is 1 second. In order for the change to be seen you would need to call `$scope.$apply()` after 1 second. This causes the error i'm talking about. Now this could be achieved by using angular's `$interval` and `$timeout` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lJAYnGUS6mliwrRrudTZ?p=preview)

Comment: ok nvmd, if you put the apply inside the `setTimeout` it works. The point is, if you want changes to apply to the view with something like setTimeout or setInterval, it's a best practice to use $timeout or $interval instead

Comment: The assertion that using `$interval` is a best practice for cases like this is the part I'm challenging. Using `$scope.apply` allows you to put only the part you need in the digest cycle, while with `$interval` the whole thing goes. What if this function performed a complex, time-consuming calculation (which is usually why people spin off a separate thread)? Using `$interval` would lead to a less responsive app because the entire function is done during the digest cycle. With `$scope.apply` only setting the property (after you've already computed the result) is on the digest cycle. Far faster.

Comment: You're right, it is dependent on the situation, as to which you should use. However `$scope.$apply()` doesn't just set one property, but all properties on the scope right? I mean you can decide which functions go inside the `$scope.$apply()` but it functionally works the same as just calling it afterward, with the exception of better possible error handling when the function is inside the function. I can't really think of a scenario where `$interval` would be slower. It still has to run the code regardless of whether or not it is in the digest cycle

Comment: Maybe you could provide a link to an example or explanation to this?

Comment: The digest cycle can't complete until that method is finished, and digest cycles run consecutively. Suppose the function takes two seconds. The interval function starts, and 1 second later the user clicks a button, and clicking that button is supposed to change text in the model, and that text is displayed on the screen. Because the update to the model caused by the click will happen on subsequent digest cycles, and since subsequent digest cycles cannot start until the current one completes, there will be a one-second lag between the time the user clicked the button and UI is updated.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your UI is not updated is because your game timer logic runs outside the regular Angular digest cycle. There's a nice article explaining it: [$watch How the $apply Runs a $digest](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/).

Instead of using `setInterval`, it is **recommended** to use Angular's [$interval service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval). It is a wrapper for `window.setInterval` and releases you from the duty of having to manually call `$scope.$apply` or "tell Angular to update the UI".

Additional benefits of using `$interval`:

> - It wraps your callback for you automatically in a try/catch block and let's you handle errors in the [$exceptionHandler service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$exceptionHandler).
> - It returns a promise and thus tends to interoperate better with other promise-based code than the traditional callback approach. When your callback returns, the value returned is used to resolved the promise.

---

An alternative solution would be to explicitly call [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) inside `setInterval` to notify Angular that "model data has changed, update the UI".

Comment: How is providing an alternative to the recommended approach "completely changing my answer"? My main point remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` does its work in a separate thread (sort of), so Angular cannot detect any changes to properties it makes. You have to wrap any functions that modifies properties with `$scope.$apply(function () {...` so that Angular detects them and pushes those changes to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

**$scope.$apply();**

Working [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/bobebehoro/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
$scope.game.timer = setInterval(function() {      
      $scope.game.timerValue -= 1;
      if( $scope.game.timerValue <= 0)
      {
        $scope.game.message = "Defeat! Time is out! Your score is " + $scope.game.score;
        clearTimeout($scope.game.timer);
      }
      $scope.$apply();
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are refreshing with a function that is outside Angular (setInterval). To tell angular to apply the change in your view, you have two solutions :
using `$scope.$apply()` :

```
$scope.startGame = function () {    

    if($scope.game.timer) clearTimeout($scope.game.timer);

    $scope.game.score = 0;
    $scope.game.wrong = "";    
    $scope.game.message = "The game started!";

    $scope.game.timer = setInterval(function() {      
      $scope.game.timerValue -= 1;
      $scope.$apply();

      if( $scope.game.timerValue <= 0)
      {
        $scope.game.message = "Defeat! Time is out! Your score is " + $scope.game.score;
        clearTimeout($scope.game.timer);
      }
    },1000);
  };
```

or using `$timeout` :

```
$scope.startGame = function () {    

    if($scope.game.timer) $timeout.cancel($scope.game.timer);

    $scope.game.score = 0;
    $scope.game.wrong = "";    
    $scope.game.message = "The game started!";

    $scope.game.timer = $timeout(function() {      
      $scope.game.timerValue -= 1;

      if( $scope.game.timerValue <= 0)
      {
        $scope.game.message = "Defeat! Time is out! Your score is " + $scope.game.score;
        $timeout.cancel($scope.game.timer);
      }
    },1000);
  };
```

Without forgetting to inject ̀`$timeout` in your controller dependencies.